# How to force a version in Bundle Gemfile?

Tags: ruby, bundler, jekyll, gemfile

This is my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'jekyll', '~> 2.4.0'
gem 'fontcustom', '~> 1.3.3'
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
$ bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "listen":
  In Gemfile:
    fontcustom (~> 1.3.3) ruby depends on
      listen (~> 1.0) ruby

    jekyll (~> 2.4.0) ruby depends on
      jekyll-watch (~> 1.1) ruby depends on
        listen (2.7.0)
```

What is a workaround? I need to use jekyll 2.4.0.

Comment: I would fork the `fontcustom` gem, change its `gemspec` and try if it also runs with `listen ~> 2.7.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone has submitted a pull request to support listen v1 and v2 in fontcustom: https://github.com/FontCustom/fontcustom/pull/191 Unfortunately, it has not been accepted yet.

You can use the forked version by changing your `Gemfile` to:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'jekyll', '~> 2.4.0'
gem 'fontcustom', git: 'https://github.com/twalpole/fontcustom.git', branch: 'listen'
```

Then, run `bundle install`.